# Where does Inversion of Control exist in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, inversion-of-control

I've read some articles (Stackoverflow, Wikipedia, Simone Busoli, etc.) about Inversion of Control (IoC) and am starting to get my head around the concept. I've also been studying the Entity Framework (EF) and am wondering where specifically IoC is present within the EF? Here's a simple EF example I've been looking at: ([EF Code First: new DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542))

Answer (score 0):

Inversion of Control is a pattern that aims at loosely coupling an *application*. It puts the application in charge of all of its dependencies (whether or not they are in libraries or frameworks).

EF is not an application, it is a library. You can wire it up with IoC, but since it is not an application, it contains no IoC.

That said, it is possible to develop frameworks and libraries to be IoC or DI (dependency injection) friendly. There are a couple of great articles on that topic:

- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/
- http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/

Mark Seemann (the author of that blog) has written a [great book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) on the subject of DI in .NET, which I highly recommend because there is a lot of misinformation and outdated information on the web about IoC and DI. I am confident once you read the book you will understand how to use IoC with EF, but it is not something that can be answered in a paragraph or two.

Comment: You stated that EF is not an application, it is a library. The articles stated that one of the key differences between a library &  framework is that IoC is present in a framework. So, if I'm understanding this correctly, although it's called "Entity Framework," it's not really a framework? Thanks for the feedback.